# Data display (filter)

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

i want to display data in a CollectionView that has state = false using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, but I don't quite understand how to do it. I wanted to use ICollectionView but didn't find it in maui. help me please

**Model**

```
public class Task 
{     
    public string Title { get; set; }     
    public string Text { get; set; }     
    public bool State { get; set; }     
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } 
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public partial class ToDoViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string title;
    [ObservableProperty]
    string text;
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool state = false;
    [ObservableProperty]
    DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Task> tasks;

    int count = 1;
    public ToDoViewModel()
    {
        tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    void Add()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return;
        Task task = new Task
        {
            Title = $"Task #{count}",
            Text = text,
            State = state,
            CreateDate = createDate
        };
        tasks.Add(task);
        count++;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    void Remove(Task task)
    {
        if (tasks.Contains(task))
            tasks.Remove(task);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    void StateDone(Task task)
    {
        task.State = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck?  Do you understand how to use CollectionView?

Comment: @Jason, i want the collectionview to have data that has state = false, but I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set a `CollectionView` :

```
public ICollectionView TasksView { get; set; }
```

When you initiate your ViewModel, you may the source of CollectionView, eventually add some sorting. Then you need to update the CollectionView filter :

```
public ToDoViewModel()
{
        tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
        TasksView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = tasks }.View;
            TasksView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Title", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        this.updateTasksView();
}
private void updateTasksView()
{
    if (ListStockBeamView != null)
    {
        TasksView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(getFilteredTasksView);
    }
}
private bool getFilteredTasksView(object obj)
{
    Task task = (Task)obj;
    if (task.State==true) return false;//you could just write return !task.State
    if(task.Title=="") return false // i.e you want to hide tasks without title
    return true;
}
```

I always set the filter in a function, because in the future, if you want to add a CheckBox, to select `state==true` or `state==false`, or even filter the text title, or any other filter, it is easy to add additive filters, then launch the function everytime you edit your filters

Comment: does maui have icollectionview?

Comment: @olololool excuse me, I have no idea about maui. try to add `using System.ComponentModel;`, then you'll have your answer

Comment: I added but it doesn't work(

Comment: what does "it doesn't work" mean? which line? which error do you have?

Comment: @ Siegfried.V, System.ComponentModel does not conatin ICollectionView in MAUI

Comment: @olololool I read that in MAUI, you have CollectionView : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0, but it seems there are differences in its implementation, here is a link with an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73414188/net-maui-pass-collectionview-item-index-to-command

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple demo for you and `CollectionView` can be used in the MAUI.

I noticed that you wrote a model file and a ViewModel file. So I write the xaml file.

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding tasks}" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title }" IsVisible="{Binding State}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Text }"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

In the xaml, I bind the state to the `IsVisible`, so you can filter the data which you want to see.

Another way to use the `state` is by using the `LINQ` to select the data which the state is true

```
var TasksQuery =
    from task in tasks
    where task.State == "true"
    select task;
```

Then you can use the TaskQuery which the state is all true.